# Error APPX1706: creating winrt dll with xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I built a WinRT(Windows phone 8.1) dll with Page.xaml and App.xaml files.
Next, I add reference to this winmd in wp8.1 application project.

And I get following error:

```
error APPX1706: The .winmd file 'project.winmd' contains type 
'?A0x32772d97.project_XamlTypeInfo.XamlMetaDataProvider' outside its root namespace
'project'. Make sure that all public types appear under a common root namespace
that matches the output file name.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A WinMD library is basically a regular library (DLL) with some metadata information. These metadata information will allow it to be used from different languages. You can for example, create a WinMD library in C# and use it from a C++ or JS application.

Since the WinMD Library can be used by different languages, they are all conforming to the Windows Runtime rules.

Your specific problem is that one of the rules for the WinMD files states that all the classes must belong to the same root namespace. 
It means that if you have the following code:

```
A.cs
namespace Foo { class A { ... } }

B.cs
namespace Foo.Sub { class B { ... } }

C.cs
namespace Bar { class C { ... } }

D.cs
namespace Bar.Sub { class D { ... } }
```

The WinMD linker will return the error you are seeing.
To solve it, you will have to declare all your classes in the same root namespace :

```
 A.cs
namespace Foo { class A { ... } }

B.cs
namespace Foo.Sub { class B { ... } }

C.cs
namespace Foo { class C { ... } }

D.cs
namespace Foo.Sub { class D { ... } }
```

I've replaced all the "Bar" namespace by "Foo"